# Material-UI TextField Outline Label is overlapping with border when conditionally rendered

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-04y5b

Steps to reproduce:

- Click "confirm" or "have a code?" to trigger a conditional render of a different form.
- Click the "Confirmation Code" `TextField`.
- Notice the border has rendered incorrectly and is causing the label to overlap with the border.
- For correct behavior initialize newUser with a value other than Null and see that the border has rendered correctly to accommodate the label.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround that can solve it will be adding a `key` to the Textbox so you force it to render a new element:

```
<TextField
  key="Confirmation Code"
  variant="outlined"
  margin="normal"
  required
  fullWidth
  id="email"
  label="Confirmation Code"
  name="email"
  autoComplete="confirmation code"
/>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. If you don't mind can you share what made you think to try adding a key?

Comment: It looked like the Confirmation Code Textfield was rendered based on the previous Textfield. see [Avoiding stateful components reuse with React keys](https://medium.com/trabe/avoiding-stateful-components-reuse-with-react-keys-2e5f6e8cc5cb)

Answer (score 10):

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label-type">Package Type</InputLabel>
                            <Select
                                labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label-type"
                                id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                                {...field}
                                required
                                label="Package Type"
                                className={classes.formControl}
                            >
                                <MenuItem value="chart">Chart</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value="email">Email</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value="social">Social</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                        </FormControl>
```

Add label="Package Type" inside select
Thats work

Comment: don't know why but this worked

Comment: To add context, it works because it adds an invisible label for the `label` text behind the actual `<InputLabel/>` that then blocks out the border from the input.  [The issue is described in this ticket](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/16833) and appears to not be slated to be fixed in MUI v4.  Not an ideal state of affairs but a viable workaround.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround posted by CD above works - but this is indeed a bug.

More discussion, as well as other potential workarounds, can be found on the Github issue.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16833

Answer (score 1):

If you're here for a Select field, you can do it with the `labelWidth` prop on `Select` with the variant on the `FormControl`.

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" style={{ minWidth: 300 }}>
  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
    Calendar to Add Event
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelWidth={150}
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    fullWidth
  >
    {menuArray}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```