# Material UI TextField border overlaps with Label

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI `TextField` and Material UI `Tab`. I have two tabs and each has a text field inside them. After I click on the `TextField`, the border should open for the label, but this doesn't happen if the current `Tab` is not the `Tab1` !!

I managed to reproduce this problem in [this CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/textfieldontabs-s2ese?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and the code is also included below.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Typography
      component="div"
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`scrollable-force-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      <Box p={1}>{children}</Box>
    </Typography>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `scrollable-force-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0
  },
  Tab: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        minWidth: "130px"
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function Demo(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  function handleChange(event, newValue) {
    setValue(newValue);
    console.log(newValue);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs
          key={"tabs"}
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="on"
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          aria-label="scrollable force tabs example"
        >
          <Tab
            key={"tab1"}
            className={classes.Tab}
            label={0}
            {...a11yProps(0)}
          />
          <Tab
            key={"tab2"}
            className={classes.Tab}
            label={1}
            {...a11yProps(1)}
          />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel
        key={"panel1"}
        value={value}
        index={0}
        style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}
      >
        <div key={"div1"}>
          hi im tab1{" "}
          <TextField
            key={"textfield1"}
            variant={"outlined"}
            margin={"dense"}
            label={"im tab 0 textfield"}
          />
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel
        key={"panel2"}
        value={value}
        index={1}
        style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}
      >
        <div key={"div2"}>
          hi im tab2
          <TextField
            key={"textfield2"}
            variant={"outlined"}
            margin={"dense"}
            label={"im tab 1 textfield"}
          />
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit1:**

I managed to find a similar question...,
[Material-UI TextField Outline Label is overlapping with border when conditionally rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455970/material-ui-textfield-outline-label-is-overlapping-with-border-when-conditionall?rq=1)
It seems this is not related to tabs as it is related to conditional rendering, which for me happened when i was using tabs

**Edit2:**
I tried giving the `Textfield` a key, but the problem still remains and there is an overlap between `Textfield` border and label, i updated the sandbox so it can reflect this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [label width is calculated](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.2/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L102) during the initial rendering of the `TextField` and is only recalculated if the label changes. During the initial rendering of the `TextField` on your second tab, the `TextField` is not visible and thus the label's width is 0. Switching the `TabPanel` to visible does **not** cause a re-calculation of the label width, so no space is allotted for it in the outline.

You can fix this by using the same approach within your `TabPanel` as is used in the demos which is to only render the children of the panel when it is visible. This allows the label width to be correctly calculated after the initial rendering.

So instead of

```
<Box p={1}>{children}</Box>
```

you should instead have

```
{value === index && <Box p={1}>{children}</Box>}
```

[image: Edit TextFieldOnTabs]

Comment: Nice. In this case, I'd also remove the `hidden` attribute to prevent further problems or put `if (value !== index) return null;` before the main return and not render the useless Typography

Comment: I was having the same problem. Your solution works like a charm, thanks !

Answer (score 6):

I had the overlap problem with the select. Slightly different scenario though. I went through numerous pages and just couldn't find a solution to these problems:

1. Label text overlapping with the border - when the focus is received
2. Placeholder text touching the left border
3. If not problem # 1 - then Placeholder text staying inside the borders even when the value is selected/entered

[image]

[image]

[image]

A simple solution to all this are the following checks that worked for me -

1. `<FormControl variant="outlined">`

Make sure variant is added.

2. `<InputLabel id="input_designationselected" style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}>Designation*</InputLabel>`

Make sure that background is set for the label. Or refer to this link here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14530

3. the attribute `labelId` for the input control/select control matches the ID of the `InputLabel`

Final output is as we need it.

[image]

It drove me crazy for days - and It thought I will share it for others also. Sorry if this is the wrong place to post it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you please provide some idea?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216947/react-material-ui-textfield-label-overlap-with-border#

Comment: The link doesn't work. You still have the problem or the points in my answer solved it? If you found other solution, please share that as well. Might help us in the future.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69217419/react-material-label-not-in-right-position-in-textfield

Comment: Can you possibly share a code sand box link or the whole code? Meanwhile remove the Margin and transform in the link above and share what happens.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same issue on mui v5, and this fix it

Comment: This almost got it working for me, but I was annoyed by the fact that the there wasn't any space around the label when the select is onfocused, but on focus, the white space expands a little bit.

I ended up targeting the legend element that gets rendered and setting max-width to 100%, which fixed it.