# What is the difference between @material-ui/core and @mui/material?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I found that the Official Website of Material UI is using `@material-ui/core` and `@mui/material`.

But I find that If I use `@material-ui/core` or `@mui/material` Textfield, the UI doesn't work and the problems are mentioned below

[React - Material label not in right position in Textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69217419/react-material-label-not-in-right-position-in-textfield)

If you search Material UI in Google, and go to `https://mui.com/`, it tells you to `npm install @mui/material`. But a few weeks ago, I am using `npm install @material-ui/core`

If I have both `@material-ui/core` and `@mui/material` in my package.json, and I include both `script` and `stylesheet` in `index.html`, will there be any conflicts that mess up the UI

**Update 1**

In `@mui` CodeSandbox,
If you try `Textfield` with `select` prop, when you open the select, `overflow: hidden` will be added in body.
[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/selecttextfields-material-demo-forked-z6b9f?file=/demo.js

In my project,
`overflow: hidden; padding: 15px` is added in body, but I checked I've done nothing about this!
[image]

Comment: @Ian Kemp the problem is that if you search Material UI in google, and go to `https://mui.com/`, it tells you to `npm install @mui/material`. But few weeks ago, I am using `npm install @material-ui`!

Comment: If I have both `@material-ui` and `@mui` in my package.json, and I include both `script` and `stylesheet` in `index.html`, will there be any conflicts which mess up the UI

Comment: @IanKemp I had searched on google and saw this. But yea material ui website is redirecting to mui.com . When I looked on npm registry site there is separate packages for both. Very wired. Does not look like they have renamed or reworked on pkg.

Comment: @CCCC Twitter is our friend this time
See updates from Material-ui
https://twitter.com/MaterialUI/status/1438518915236126723?s=20

Answer (score 39):

Material UI v1, v3, and v4 are available on npm under [`@material-ui/core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core).

Material UI v5 and above are available on npm under [`@mui/material`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material).

It's the same library, but they changed the npm package name in version 5.

Comment: @GabRAMturn can I use them in the same project I think they are nor correctly installed because I used `--legacy-peer-deps` ?

Answer (score 14):

Since Sep 16, 2021, the organization behind Material UI changed its name to MUI to differentiate the company from Google. They say on the blog:

> We are breaking the strong association with Material Design as we have
> seen too many people confusing Material UI with Google, or as a
> synonym of Material Design.

Blog post here: https://mui.com/blog/material-ui-is-now-mui/

However, the open-source project name didn't change. It's still called Material UI.

From version 5 the packages are stored under `@mui/material` as you can find in the documentation and you must use `npm install @mui/material` instead of `@material-ui/core`.

Answer (score 9):

Material ui has upgraded to V5 as per the recent tweet :https://twitter.com/MaterialUI/status/1438518915236126723?s=20

[image]