# React Material UI: Appbar gave TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '100')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui, appbar

I am making a multi step form for which I was using Material UI  component. But the moment I import it, it shows error.
The code is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

function FormUserDetails({ nextstep, values }) {

    const proceed = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        nextstep();
    }
    return (
        <ThemeProvider>
            <React.Fragment>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                            News
                        </Typography>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </React.Fragment>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}

export default FormUserDetails
```

Now the error looks like this:
`

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '100')
> (anonymous function) C:/Users/edkni/Documents/projects/multi-step
> form/state_form/node_modules/@mui/material/AppBar/AppBar.js:40
> 37 | theme,
> 38 |   ownerState
> 39 | }) => {
> 40 |   const backgroundColorDefault = theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? theme.palette.grey[100] : theme.palette.grey[900];
> 41 |   return _extends({
> 42 |     display: 'flex',
> 43 |     flexDirection: 'column',View compiled transformedStyleArg
> C:/Users/edkni/Documents/projects/multi-step form/state_form/node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createStyled.js:175
> 172 |   } = _ref2,
> 173 |       other = _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(_ref2, _excluded3);
> 174 |
> 175 |   return styleArg(_extends({
> 176 |     theme: isEmpty(themeInput) ? defaultTheme : themeInput
> 177 |   }, other));
> 178 | };

I have no idea what that means. It would be great help if someone could answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [MUI](https://mui.com/customization/theming/) documents:

> If you wish to customize the theme, you need to use the ThemeProvider
> component in order to inject a theme into your application.

So `theme` property in `ThemeProvider` component is required. You should inject a `theme` to it:

```
import React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { orange } from "@mui/material/colors";

function FormUserDetails({ nextstep, values }) {
  // const proceed = (e) => {
  //   e.preventDefault();
  //   nextstep();
  // };

  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: orange[500]
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            News
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return <FormUserDetails />;
}
```

[image: Edit awesome-hodgkin-i3hlp]

Comment: Thank you man, this really worked.  From this preference I think a lot has changed too. Where do you think I should start to grasp all of the changes?

Comment: @SunilShah Anytime! Try look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69219552/what-is-the-difference-between-material-ui-and-mui